# Slick Carousel custom paging not setting dynamic data-attributes

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I have a webpage that shows a product listing (dynamically loaded from a db). Each product has a ‘Quick View’ button which a user can click and a modal pops up showing a slick carousel of images of the product and its name. However, the modal carousel doesn't set the right data attribute after the first click.

In brief what I want to do is this;
When the user clicks the ‘Quick View’ button;

1. Get the 3 data attributes (image path, thumbnail image path, name) from the button element
2. Set the attributes as attributes in the modal element
3. Attach the modal to slick and then show the modal

Here is my code;
I have tried take out much of the unimportant stuff and post the relevant parts.

```html
<!--the button that is clicked-->
<div>
  <a href='#' class="block2-btn js-show-modal1" data-pdct-img="image.jpg" data-pdct-name="shoe1">
    Quick View
  </a>
</div>


<!--the code for the modal - initially it's hidden, pops up on click of the button above-->
<div class="wrap-modal1 js-modal1">
 <div class="overlay-modal1 js-hide-modal1"></div>
    <button class="js-hide-modal1">
     <img src="images/icons/icon-close.png" alt="CLOSE">
    </button>

    <div class="wrap-slick3">
     <div class="wrap-slick3-dots"></div>
     <div class="wrap-slick3-arrows"></div>
     <div class="slick3 gallery-lb">            
      <div class="item-slick3" data-thumb="" id="pdct_img_1_thumb">                                  
       <div class="wrap-pic-w pos-relative">
        <img src="" alt="IMG-PRODUCT" id="pdct_img_1">                                   
        <a href="" id="pdct_img_1_large">                           
         <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>                                        
        </a>
        </div>                              
       </div>                               
       <!--other thumbnails-->                                   
      </div>                
      <div>
        <h4 id="product_name"></h4>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

```
        $('.js-show-modal1').on('click', function(){
            //e.preventDefault();

            var name = $(this).attr("data-pdct-name");
            var img = $(this).attr("data-pdct-img");

            $("#product_name").html(name);
            $("#pdct_img_1").attr('src','images2/'+img);
            $("#pdct_img_1_thumb").attr("data-thumb",'images2/'+img);
            $("#pdct_img_1_large").attr('href','images2/'+img);
            $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');


            $('.wrap-slick3').each(function(){
                $(this).find('.slick3').slick({
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    fade: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    autoplaySpeed: 6000,

                    arrows: true,
                    appendArrows: $(this).find('.wrap-slick3-arrows'),
                    prevArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick3 prev-slick3"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
                    nextArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick3 next-slick3"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',

                    dots: true,
                    appendDots: $(this).find('.wrap-slick3-dots'),
                    dotsClass:'slick3-dots',
                    customPaging: function(slick, index) {
                        var portrait = $(slick.$slides[index]).data('thumb');
                        return '<img src=" ' + portrait + ' "/><div class="slick3-dot-overlay"></div>';
                    },  
                });
            });
        });     

        $('.js-hide-modal1').on('click',function(){
            $('.js-modal1').removeClass('show-modal1');
        });
```

This is the problem;
When I click the ‘Quick View’ button the first time, every attribute is set correctly in the modal.
When I close the modal and click on another ‘Quick View’ button, the thumbnail image path of the first button I clicked is what persists for any consequent buttons I clicked thereafter.

I am quite stuck on what I need to do to have the slick carousel pick up the right data attribute in the custom paging function (for the thumbnail image). I'm happy to clarify on anything that may not have come out clearly.

Any guidance is much appreciated. 
[image: This is when the quick view button is clicked first. The thumbnails are set correctly]

[image: When another button is clicked, you can see that the new (correct) thumbnails for that picture haven't been set; the first ones persist]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to solve this and thought i would post the answer in case someone finds it useful in the future.

I was new to slick so I didn't know this; the important thing to understand about a slick carousel is that it is effectively an array of slides. The carousel(array) is modified not by html/javascript actions but by using slick to add and remove slides to the array (carousel) - where a slide in this case is formatted html to display an image or any element for that matter.

With the above in mind, closing the modal in the question (and setting new data-attributes values) does not change the thumbnails/slides in the carousel. To change the slides to those of the new product, you have to first remove the previous values from the slick(upon closing the modal), then add the new ones(upon opening a modal). This solution may be a bit 'hacky' but it does the required job.
This is the code;

```
   //set the slick options outside the click event handler
   $('.wrap-slick3').each(function(){
     $(this).find('.slick3').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,

        arrows: true,
        appendArrows: $(this).find('.wrap-slick3-arrows'),
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $(this).find('.wrap-slick3-dots'),
        dotsClass:'slick3-dots',
        //remove customPaging because slides are now to be added independently --- see below
     });
   });



   $('.js-show-modal1').on('click', function(){       //click to open modal
     var name = $(this).attr("data-pdct-name");
     var img = $(this).attr("data-pdct-img");

     $("#product_name").html(name);     //set other stuff in the modal

     //add new slides to slick (i.e, every time a modal is opened, construct a new carousel)
     $(".wrap-slick3").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".slick3").slick("slickAdd","<div class='item-slick3' 
             data-thumb='images2/"+img+"'>       
             <div class='wrap-pic-w pos-relative'> 
              <img src='images2/"+img+"'  alt='IMG-PRODUCT'> 
              <a class='' href='images2/"+img+"'>
               <i class='fa fa-expand'></i>
              </a> 
             </div> 
            </div>"); //have limited it to one slide for demo purposes
     });
     $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');   //then display the modal
   }):    
   //end of modal open/click actions

   //Actions for when the modal is closed
   $('.js-hide-modal1').on('click',function(){
      $('.js-modal1').removeClass('show-modal1');    //close the modal

      //after closing the modal, (empty)remove all the previous slides from the carousel
      $('.wrap-slick3').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.slick3').slick('slickRemove',null,null,true);
      });
   });
```

```html
<!--Finally modify the html to remove the code for the slides -- because this is now being inserted(added) with slick; see JS above-->
<div class="wrap-modal1 js-modal1">
 <div class="overlay-modal1 js-hide-modal1"></div>
    <button class="js-hide-modal1">
     <img src="images/icons/icon-close.png" alt="CLOSE">
    </button>

    <div class="wrap-slick3">
     <div class="wrap-slick3-dots"></div>
     <div class="wrap-slick3-arrows"></div>
     <div class="slick3">
       <!--code for the slides will be inserted here using the above JS-->                                   
     </div>                
    <div>
     <h4 id="product_name"></h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

That's how you can achieve the desired effect!

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me to resolve my problem with slick!